# ChromeDriver/Selenium take a black screenshot when in a separate tab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, adblock

I'm currently writing a visual test that require adblock to be installed to stop some ads from ruining the test. However when I run the Chromedriver with the adblock extension installed it brings up the successfully installed adblock tab. This tab screws up my screenshots because the driver is working in a previous tab that opens. Is there any way to stop the adblock tab from opening or prevent the black screenshot from happening? Here is the initialization for the driver.

```
def setUp(self):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_extension('AdBlock_v2.6.4.crx')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', port=0, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

Comment: found answer will post when I'm allowed unformatted answer ----->   def test_sauce(self):
  time.sleep(5)
  handles = self.driver.window_handles
  self.driver.switch_to_window(handles[-1])


seems to be the best way to handle it. It simply tells the driver to switch to the tab which is considered a window. I feel silly for trying to find a more complex solution.

Comment: You can post a real answer instead of a comment to your own question.

Comment: I can't immediately as a new user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handles = self.driver.window_handles
self.driver.switch_to_window(handles[-1])
```

seems to be the best way to handle it. It simply tells the driver to switch to the tab which is considered a window. I feel silly for trying to find a more complex solution